# Is there anyway to rip off 3D models from games like this? (Black Desert Online)

Tags: modeling, materials, game-engine, 3d-view, edit-mode

Is there anyway to rip off 3D models from games like this? (Black Desert Online)
I want to use the faces as a base for my sculptures.

Thank you guys!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not directly related to using blender.

Answer (score 0):

yes but also no, specificly from black desert im not shure. But for example if you have a source engine game you need a rooting tool and a object converter just to open the mesh and since different engines use different formats (Moustly) you need to find the right ones to import models from source game in blender i need thiese 3 programs 1st to export modell as .obj file 2nd to convert textures and 3rd to find the modells [image]